# Using pagedown/markdown in Django together with Bootstrap

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, pagedown

I use Django 1.6.4 and I want to create a site for a scholarship (kleyboldt) where you can see the latest news. It is my aim to create a user friendly admin page where also people without any knowledge in html or css are able to format their text. Therefore I decided to use Markdown (should be similar to the stackflow site where you can ask your question).

For designing my page I use Twitter Bootstrap 3.0. Now I try to find an app that combines pagedown and Bootstrap. It would be great to have the possibility to write additional css classes in order to style the output of the markdown parser (e.g. style lists etc.).

I will need an app like this for various cases on this site, but I would like to start with the news. My model for a entry is:

**kleyboldt_homepage/homepage/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class news_entry(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date        = models.DateField()
    content     = models.TextField()
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='news/', blank=True, null=True)   

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I found [django-pagedown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/), [pagedown-bootstrap](https://github.com/samwillis/pagedown-bootstrap) and [django-pagedown-bootstrap](https://bitbucket.org/Erve/django-pagedown-bootstrap/overview) but I have problems to combine them into a working example. Would anybody be so glad to give me a working example for that?